# Negative log likelihood cholesky decomposition

Tags: r, likelihood, spatial

The code in question comes from [Spatial Data Science by Pebesma and Bivand](https://r-spatial.org/book/12-Interpolation.html#fitting-variogram-models). I can pretty much understand what it says except for the last line. How does this give the negative log likelihood? I've tried looking for a proof online but haven't had much luck.

```
# negative log likelihood, excluding the constant:
nll <- function(x, d, res, model, ...) {
m <- get_model(x, model, ...)
Q <- variogramLine(m, dist_vector = d, covariance = TRUE)
Qc <- chol(Q)
det <- 2 * sum(log(diag(Qc)))
det + t(res) %*% ch_solve(Qc, res)
}
```

Comment: The last 3 lines compute the negative log likelihood of the multivariate normal `res ~ normal(0, Q)` using some linear algebra. `det` stands for determinant. See these notes on [Evaluating the multivariate normal density](https://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/ahonkela/teaching/compstats1/book/multivariate-normal-distributions-and-numerical-linear-algebra.html#evaluating-the-multivariate-normal-density).